# NB-IoT: open/close PDP/bearer for each transmission or keep constantly open?

Tags: iot, lte

What is the "right strategy" to communicate from sensor to network?

Assuming sensor sends data every 5 minutes or maybe every 60 minutes should I activate PDP context and open bearer for each transmission, and then close bearer and deactivate PDP context after transmission is done, or should I keep them open constantly?